# Savings data to a csv file using pandas and yahoo finance

Tags: pandas, csv, saving-data

I'm trying to extract yahoo finance data and store it in a CSV file. For example, I'm trying to extract 'Adj Close' prices for IBM and store the data into a csv file. Here's what I have so far.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame as df

ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='ibm', start=datetime(2018, 1, 1), end=datetime(2019,4,28))

Adj_Close = df(ibm['Adj Close'])
```

What do I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: What's not working currently?

Answer (score 2):

You can first print the object ibm to see the data structure it returns. It is a nested dictionary and not a data frame.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime
ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='ibm', start=datetime(2018, 1, 1), end=datetime(2019,4,28))

type(ibm)

dict
```

You can access Adj Close in the nested dict and write the data to csv.

```
ibm['prices']['Adj Close'].to_csv('ibm.csv', header = True)
```

If you read the ibm.csv, you get

```
df = pd.read_csv('ibm.csv')

    Date        Adj Close
0   2018-01-02  145.875259
1   2018-01-03  149.885071
2   2018-01-04  152.920776
3   2018-01-05  153.667892
4   2018-01-08  154.594681
```